# haskell propositional logic

Tags: haskell, logic

I am trying to create a structure for propositional logic in haskell. This structure contains "AND", "OR" and "Equalities" and "Inequalities" of "Variables (instead of just Variables).
The programm I want to build should check if a new "Equality"/"Inequality" satisfies the previous ones and add it and should the occasion arise delete some, to let it be correct.

```
data Logic a = Val a 
              | And     (Logic a) (Logic a)
              | Or      (Logic a) (Logic a)
              | Equal   (Logic a) (Logic a)
              | Inequal (Logic a) (Logic a)
              | Parenthesis (Logic a) 
              deriving (Show, Eq)

equal :: Eq a => Logic a -> Logic a -> Bool
equal (Equal a b) (Equal c d) 
    | a == c && b == d = True
    | a == d && b == c = True
    | otherwise = False

eq (Equal a b) (Inequal c d) = False
eq1 (Inequal a b) (Equal c d ) = False

inequal :: Eq a => Logic a -> Logic a -> Bool    
inequal (Inequal a b) (Inequal c d) 
    | a == c && b == d = True
    | a == d && b == c = True
    | otherwise = False
```

This is what I got so far. I am quite confused since I don't know how to manage the problem, that if I have a new "Inequality" or "Equality" to check how to handle it, because I can't check like:

```
check logic = if logic == (Equal a) then something else somethingelse
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what `eq` and `eq1` are supposed to be; right now, they are just partial functions of type `Logic a -> Logic a -> Bool`, rather than Prolog-like statements of fact. Also, you need to define an `Eq` instance for `Logic a`.

Comment: I am a bit confused - do you want to "validate" if your `Logic` is `True` something like `validate $ Equal (Val 'a') (Val 'a') ~> True`. Then my question would be what is `validate $ Val 'a'`? Or do you want to create an equivalence relation between two `Logic` - like `equiv (And (Equal (Val 'a') (Val 'a')) (Equal (Val 'a') (Val 'b'))) (And (Equal (Val 'a') (Val 'b')) (Equal (Val 'a') (Val 'a')))` should be `True`.

Comment: I want to build a function check:
check :: Logic a -> Logic a -> Logic a
check (logic1) (logic2) = "checks if I can add logic1 to logic2 and if neccesary modifies logic2.
E.g. check (a=b) ((a/=b "or" a/=c) "and" (d=e)) should return:
(a/=c) "and" (d=e)

Comment: So make a combined theory solver where you replace each logical statement with a boolean and find a satisfying assignment. Remove the terms that correspond with any value that the SAT solver set to False.

Comment: And how should something like this look like? sorry I am not too much into this topic.

Comment: It would help to understand if this is for you or for class. If this is for you then use SBV. If it's for class then I doubt that is what the instructor expects and it might not be wanted.

Comment: it is a project for the university

Comment: You need to discuss this with your professor or TA. I strongly suspect that you have misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: There is no restriction from the university. It is just an idea I came up with to solve a problem.